# Boost Program Options short name issue

Tags: c++, boost, command-line, boost-program-options

I am using boost/program_options for my CLI application.

I am reading a variable named *name* from the user.

The variable CLI option called --name or -n for short name.

When i execute

```
... --name val ...
```

the variable is set to val (as expected).

But when i execute (accidentally)

```
... -name val ...
```

the variable is set to ame.

How can i configure boost to block this scenario ?

Comment: Maybe turn off [`short_allow_adjacent`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/command_line_style/style_t.html#boost.program_options.command_line_style.style_t.short_allow_adjacent) ?

Comment: Tried it, didn't work :-)